# Number of element which can be sorted using heapsort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, runtime, time-complexity

i faced a very confusing problem in the examination and attempted it wrong, it was an objective type problem, given four options , Now i know the correct option but i have no explanation.

**Problem :**

Number of elements which can be sorted in Ɵ(logn) time using heapsort is

a) Ɵ(1)

b) Ɵ(√ log n)

c) Ɵ(log n / loglog n)

d) Ɵ(log n)

**Option c is correct.**

i had selected the the option a), i thought in log n time only one element will be sorted, it was wrong, i don't know why option c) is correct.

Comment: Seems like a strangely phrased question. Isn't the `n` in the expression O(log n) for the time complexity of the heap sort the number of elements? I must be missing something.

Comment: @Mikeb I agree, this is very odd phrasing. Not just that the input size isn't `n`, but the question asks for Theta bounds on heapsort, which it just doesn't have in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that the question asks for a Theta bound on heap sort, which it doesn't have in the general case, here is why this is confusing:

When dealing with Landau notation (= O, Ɵ, Omega stuff), we are used to be given the input size as `n`; what you're being asked here is "what do we have to set the input size to to get a complexity of Ɵ(log n)".

For example: consider list traversal; this will take you `O(n)` for lists of size `n`. On the other hand, if we limit the input to `log n` for some `n`, we get a complexity of `O(log n)`. Transferring this idea to sorting algorithms, we know that heap sort has a worst case complexity of `O(n log n)` if we give it a list of size `n`. So what happens if we give it a list of size `log n`? The complexity becomes less: we go from `(n) log (n)` to

`(log n) log (log n) = log n log log n`

Now to explain why c) was the right answer, I'll write `l(n)` instead of `log n` to make it slightly more readable.

Adjust the input size in the term `n * l(n)` to `l(n)/l(l(n))` which is what c) states. We then get:

```
l(n)/l(l(n)) * l(l(n)/l(l(n)))
= l(n)/l(l(n)) * [l(l(n) - l(l(l(n)))]
= l(n) - [l(n) * l(l(l(n)))]/l(l(n))
```

As you can see (hopefully), the dominating term is `l(n) = log n`, so for inputs of the size `l(n)/l(l(n))`, heap sort has a worst case complexity of `O(log n)`. The Theta however is definitely wrong for the general case.

Side note: does anyone know how to make the terms pretty? I know we don't have LaTeX inline here, but this doesn't look nice at all.

Comment: For a more complete explanation - `lln > llln`, so `llln/lln < 1`, so `ln > ln*llln/lln`, so `ln` is the dominating term. Also, I think using `log` would've been more readable than `l`.

Answer (score 0):

Let t=exp(n) be the time you have, and m be the number of items you can sort in that time.

a) m = Θ(1) ⇒ t → ∞: You can only sort a finite number of items, no matter the time.
b) m = Θ(√t) ⇒ t = Θ(m²): you need quadratic time. Stupid bubble sort.
c) m = Θ(t/log t) ⇒ t = Θ(m log m): this is the complexity you know for heap sort.
d) m = Θ(t) ⇒ t = Θ(m): linear time sorting is too good to be true.

I must confess that the conversion for c) is mostly based on “gut feeling”. I'm reasonably confident that it is right or at least “almost correct”, but I don't know the formal rules I used to show this.